# rabbitmq consume function / channel.ack

Tags: typescript, rabbitmq

I have the following function to consume on my rabbitmq with typescript:

```
  async consume(
    queue: string,
    callback: (message: ConsumeMessage | null) => void,
  ) {
    return this.channel.consume(queue, message => {
      callback(message);
      this.channel.ack(message);
    });
  }
```

the channel. consume receives the queue, and the message with the type ConsumeMessage
but this.channel.ack needs to receive a MESSAGE type from lib amqlib as a parameter

but as my message is Consume Message I am getting the following error:

> Argument of type 'ConsumeMessage | null 'is not assignable to
> parameter of type' Message '.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type
> 'Message'.ts (2345)

when I try to use .ack

I also have doubts about how I could implement the treatment in case of an error

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because you can't use (what I presume is) your custom `ConsumeMessage | null` type where a `amqplib.Message | null` is needed. The TypeScript compiler can only guarantee that an object matching `Message` will be passed into the callback, and it *can't* guarantee that your extra properties will be there.

> I also have doubts about how I could implement the treatment in case of an error

You'll probably want to add an `err` argument as the first argument to your callback, and call it with a custom error if `message` is `null`, which [happens when the consumer is cancelled](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channelconsume). I'm assuming that you're using `amqplib/callback_api`.